# Should the <del> and <ins> tag be avoided?

Tags: html, css

The `<del>` and `<ins>` tags are supposed to represent editorial changes, so one would expect that they are used in diffs and similar situations. However, it seems they are not frequently used.

As an example, consider [github](/questions/tagged/github) or the revision history here on SO. Both use spans but not these tags.

Are there any reasons why one should not use these tags and use instead manual divs/spans?

Comment: Use spans purely for visual effects, del/ins for when you want the semantic meaning attached to that effect

Answer (score 1):

You should use these tags where ever possible as they provide *semantic meaning* to the content. This means that assistive technologies such as screen readers can understand the content better and announce them accordingly.

Simply styling your content to do this will not be read as if it was just regular text when in fact it's quite the opposite.

For example, the following:

```
<style>
.strikethrough { /*...*/}
</style>
Some <span class="strikethrough">example</span> text
```

Would be read "Some example text", whereas:

```
Some <del>example</del> text
```

Could be read "Some deleted text start example deleted text end text". This would depend on the screen reader being used.

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers render `<ins>` tag as this CSS:

```
ins {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

The `<del>` tag is usually rendered the same as `<s>` (strikethrough tag).

There is nothing wrong with these tags and they are fully supported. Only that `<u>` and `<s>` do effectively the same thing and are much more popular (minus any semantic meaning).